# Rails 3 and AuthLogic Email Activation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

Working with Rails 3 and Authlogic. I am following the steps on this tutorial: http://bit.ly/l8YOGg.

Signup/login/logout are all working fine and now I am adding email activation.  I have used all the code exactly as listed on the tutorial, and when I attempt to sign in as a new user I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#create
undefined method `activate_account_url' for #<Notifier:0x00000103c4c9b8>

app/mailers/notifier.rb:6:in `activation_instructions'
app/models/user.rb:21:in `send_activation_instructions!'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

Can't find anything in the Authlogic documentation or elsewhere that helps.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

activate_account_url should be a named route. Did you define your routes correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To find the correct route name, check `rake routes`, in particular `rake routes | grep activate`. Then put the correct route name into `notifier.rb` on line 6.